# Append a counter to a set

Tags: python, list, set

I have a `for` loop where I count in `i in range(0, 999999999)` and I want to add these in a `set` with a second variable, for example (pseudo code):

```
import random

the_set = set()
for i in range(0, 999999999):
    x = random.randint(0,100)
    the_set.append(str(i)+":"+str(x))
```

`i` and `x` are example variables where in this case the elements in the set are always unique, I understand that, but with the actual variables non-uniques may occur but shouldn't be in the set.

How do I define such a `set` and `.append()` values?

Comment: 999999999 seems extremely large.  If you really want that many elements, don't do what I'm about to suggest.  If you can afford to waste the memory temporarily, you could consider: `s = set(["%d:%d" % (i, random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(999999999)])`

Comment: I think you mean `range(0, 1000000000)` or just `range(1000000000)` as the second parameter is the *size* of the range, so `range(N)` is 0 .. N-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python `set` doesn't have `append` method, but they have `add`. So, you can do

```
the_set.add(str(i)+":"+str(x))
```

In this case, you can simply use set comprehension, like this

```
the_set = {"{}:{}".format(i, random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(999999999)}
```

But the actual problem here is `999999999`. It is a very big number. So, its not advisable to build a set of that size and holding it in memory. If you are just going to use this as a unique number generator, you can simply use a generator, like this

```
def get_next_number(max_number):
    for i in xrange(max_number): # use `range` if you are using Python 3.x
        yield "{}:{}".format(i, random.randint(0,100))
```

And then you can use it in a loop like this

```
for new_number in get_next_number(999999999):
    print new_number
```

Comment: perfect.. just what I needed. Am I correct to say, when I add an existing entry it just skips it?

Comment: If you add an existing value to a set it will skip yes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to ignore `x` if it has already been generated, I think you might want to use a dictionary instead:

```
the_dict()
for i in range(0, 999999999):
    x = random.randint(0,100)
    if the_dict.has_key(x):
        continue
    the_dict[x] = i
```

you could build the resulting set afterward:

```
the_set = {'%i:%i' % (value, key) for key, value in the_dict.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 0):

`the_set = {'{}:{}'.format(i, random.randint(0,100)) for i in xrange(10)}`